# Print each list element in a different row with a string repeating before each element Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to print a string in front of each element of a list which in turn is printed in a new row:

Example:

```
    test = ["aaa", "bee", "cee"]
    print("hello, %s" % "\n".join(storageVolume))
```

What I get from this is:

```
    hello, aaa
    bee
    cee
```

What I want is:

```
    hello, aaa
    hello, bee
    hello, cee
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: and `storageVolume` comes from... ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for x in test:
    print "Hello, {0}".format(x)
```

Comment: My bad, it's corrected now. one-liners with print don't play nice in python.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [10]: test = ["aaa", "bee", "cee"]

In [11]: print "\n".join("hello, "+x for x in test)
hello, aaa
hello, bee
hello, cee
```

or:

```
In [13]: print "\n".join("hello,  {0}".format(x) for x in test)
hello,  aaa
hello,  bee
hello,  cee
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [51]: test = ["aaa", "bee", "cee"]

In [52]: for elem in test:
   ....:     print "hello,", elem
   ....:
hello, aaa
hello, bee
hello, cee
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     for i in range(len(test)):
        print "Hello, "+(test[i]);
```

Comment: `for i in range(len(test))` is definitely preferred to `for i in range(test.__len__())`.  Although here, it's much better to just iterate over `test` directly.  `for elem in test: print "Hello,"+elem`

Comment: `test` can be directly iterated over, without needing to specify a range. (`test.__iter__()` is available)